# Cannot find directory in pycharm [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, directory, pycharm

I would like list the folder name in Oasis_3_3D in txt file but system cannot find the directory.

```
import os

start_path = '~/MLMI/m3ae/Oasis_3_3D'

if os.path.exists(start_path) and os.path.isdir(start_path):

    folder_names = [d for d in os.listdir(start_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(start_path, d))]


    with open('folder_list.txt', 'w') as f:
        for folder in folder_names:
            f.write("%s\n" % folder)

    print('Folders have been written to folder_list.txt.')
else:
    print(f"The directory {start_path} does not exist.")
```

Result:
The directory ~/MLMI/m3ae/Oasis_3_3D does not exist.

If I don't utulize if function to check, the result is [Errno 2] No such file or directory

but it correctly exists in the project file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the tilde symbol ("~"). Python treats it as a regular symbol. To expand it you should use [os.path.expanduser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).

```
elebur@pc:~$ touch ~/test.txt

elebur@pc:~$ python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.path.exists("~/test.txt")
False
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser("~/test.txt"))
True
```